# jenkins docker daemon running?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am running through creating a pipeline and I am getting the below from the error log

```
+ docker pull maven:3.3.3
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
[root@centos ~]# systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-09-07 14:43:36 EDT; 18min ago
```

I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: service docker status, can you check this?

Comment: [root@centos ~]# service docker status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-09-07 14:43:36 EDT; 26min ago

Comment: Is jenkins running inside docker? are you able to launch docker commands on the machine? Also what user is launching the jenkins script (check using whoami inside job), is this user allowed to issue docker commands?

Comment: This is most likely a permissions issue, make sure the user that jenkins is using can execute docker commands, the error "are you sure the daemon is running" is commonly because the current user does not have permissions to contact the daemon

Comment: I have installed Jenkins via wget, and it is not running inside a container.

Comment: Do I need to create a jenkins user?

Comment: jenkins user is there.. but i can't enter docker pull commands as it is asking about docker daemon. What permissions do I need to add?

Comment: Fixed. Changed the Jenkins user to root and it works

Comment: Add the jenkins user to the `docker` group - then you don't need to run as root.

Comment: thanks all for the help